# how to run glm function in R stats package from spark using opencpu

Tags: java, r, apache-spark, opencpu

how to run glm function in R stats package from spark using opencpu.I dont know as  how will we pass data from spark to glm function using java.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/onetapbeyond/opencpu-spark-executor

Comment: but Jeroen how to pass the data........??